# Comment décomposer « Il n'y a plus qu'à » ?

Tags: sens, traduction, syntaxe

J'ai trouvé [sur wordreference.com](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1251191&p=6403819#post6403819):

> Without the ***plus***, the expression could be saying that all they have to do is to split up.
>
> The ***plus*** adds the idea of there being nothing else left where there once had been something; it's the **ne...que** which supplies the idea of only.

1. Comment déduire quelle sont les particules de négation ici ? *Ne* + *plus* ? Ou *ne* + *que* ?
2. De plus, je conjecture que « il n'y a qu'à » signifie « there is only to ».
   Si je suis exact, comment traduire « Il n'y a *plus*  qu'à » ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Il n'y a plus qu'à [recommencer]* signifie « la seule chose qui reste à faire c'est [recommencer] ». C'est très similaire à *Il n'y a qu'à [regarder]*, qui signifie grosso modo  « la chose qu'il suffit de faire c'est [regarder] ».

Et en ce qui concerne la décomposition et les liens avec l'anglais  :

- *il* : pronom impersonnel
- *ne* : indique une négation (qui sera explicitée plus tard par des adverbes appropriés).
- *y avoir* : locution introductive (*there is*)
- *plus* : adverbe (généralement combiné dans la négation *ne … plus*) qui indique un changement de situation. S'il s'agissait d'une négation habituelle (mais ce n'est pas le cas, voir le point suivant) la combinaison correspondrait en anglais à *not anymore*. Mais c'est mieux de penser indépendamment de la négation à *now* ou *right now*.
- *que* : adverbe (combiné dans la négation : *ne* … *que*) qui plutôt qu'indiquer une négation complète indique une seule possibilité (*nothing but*, ou bien, dit autrement, *only*) et qui est suivi par un complément. Dans le cas un peu particulier de la locution *il y a*, ce complément peut être une proposition infinitive introduite par la préposition *à* qui indique « la seule chose qu'il suffit de faire ».

Voici autre exemple, plus simple, qui utilise à la fois *plus* et *que* dans une tournure négative :

> Elle ne pense plus qu'à son boulot.

En anglais ça donnerait « *Now, she only thinks about her job.* », mais pour aider à comprendre on peut tourner ça de cette façon : « *She can't think about anything but her job anymore* ».

Answer (score 2):

La structure de l'expression est basée sur *ne ... que* et a un sens de négation relative, ou d'affirmation restreinte pour l'action qui suit.

*Il n'y a qu'à [verbe]*, une seule action limitée par le *ne ... que*

- Il n'y a *rien à faire sauf* [verbe]
- Il y a *à faire seulement* [verbe]

*Il n'y a plus qu'à [verbe]*, on a constaté que les actions antérieures étaient achevées, la dernière action à engager est indiquée par le *plus* de *ne ... que*.

- Il ne *reste* qu'à [verbe]
- Il *reste comme dernière action* à [verbe]

Pour la catégorie du mot *plus*, je laisse la plume aux lecteurs de Maurice Grévisse et aux futurs académiciens qui fréquentent ce site ... qui curieusement s'affiche en *[gros bêta](http://www.paroles-musique.com/paroles-Comptine-Maman_Les_Ptits_Bateaux-lyrics,p143557)* !